# Número de páginas em página php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma página em *PHP* onde fiz a paginação que está funcionando perfeitamente, porém notei que a tela está ficando cheia de *links* com a numeração das páginas.

Atualmente apresento somente 3 resultados a cada página. Teriam como me ajudar a limitar o número de *links* da paginação?

Tentei fazer esse limite, porém sempre a página aumenta um número para +.
Já consegui limitar no início, quando passo para a próxima página o número de links aumenta ao infinito!

**Segue o código:**

```html
<?php
}
//PAGINAÇAO
if ($registros_ > 3) {
//Verificar a pagina anterior e posterior

 
 $max_links = 8;
 
 $links_laterais = ceil($max_links / 2);
 
 $pagina_anterior = $pagina - $links_laterais;
    $pagina_posterior = $pagina + $links_laterais;
 
    print "<div class='container'>
<div>
    <ul class='pagination'>
     <li>";
    if ($pagina_anterior > 0) {
        print "<a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$pagina_anterior&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro' aria-label='Previous'>
                                <span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>
                            </a>";
    } else {
        print "<span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>";
    }
    print "</li>";
//Apresentar a paginacao

    for ($i = $pagina_anterior; $i < $pagina_posterior; $i++) {
     if ($i >=1){ 
        print"<li><a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$i&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro'>$i</a></li>";
    }
 }
 
    print "<li>";
    if ($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina) {
        print " <a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$pagina_posterior&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro' aria-label='Previous'>
            <span aria-hidden='true''>&raquo;</span>
        </a>";
    } else {
        print "<span aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span>";
    }
    print "</div></div>";
}
//F
```

Consegui resolver meu problema! Segue o código para quem tiver a mesma dificuldade.

```html
<?php
}
//PAGINAÇAO
if ($registros_ > 3) {
//Verificar a pagina anterior e posterior

 
 $max_links = 6;
 
 $links_laterais = ceil($max_links / 3);
 
 $pagina_anterior = $pagina - $links_laterais;
    $pagina_posterior = $pagina + $links_laterais;
 
    print "<div class='container'>
<div>
    <ul class='pagination'>
     <li>";
    if ($pagina_anterior > 0) {
        print "<a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$pagina_anterior&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro' aria-label='Previous'>
                                <span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>
                            </a>";
    } else {
        print "<span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>";
    }
    print "</li>";
//Apresentar a paginacao

    for ($i = $pagina_anterior; $i < $pagina_posterior; $i++) {
     if (($i >=1) && ($i <= $num_pagina)){ 
        print"<li><a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$i&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro'>$i</a></li>";
    }
 }
 
    print "<li>";
    if ($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina) {
        print " <a href='pesquisas.php?pagina=$pagina_posterior&tipo=$tipo&seletor=$seletor&filtro=$filtro' aria-label='Previous'>
            <span aria-hidden='true''>&raquo;</span>
        </a>";
    } else {
        print "<span aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span>";
    }
    print "</div></div>";
}
//FIM PAGINAÇAO
?>
```

Comment: Você está abrindo muitas *tags, porém não está fechando-as. `$num_pagina` está recebendo qual valor?

Comment: Opa amigo, $quantidade_pg = 3; / $num_pagina = ceil($registros_/$quantidade_pg);

Comment: Já tentou substituir `$limite + 1` por `$limite`? Ps.: Evite utilizar o *Snippet*, ele não funciona com PHP.

Comment: já tentei e não deu certo sempre ultrapassa

Comment: Coloque a solução que encontrou como uma resposta e, depois, pode aceita-la